# Making titles of posts appear on mouseover/hover while image rolls up

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, twig

So, I have a div flex which takes 3 posts from wordpress using **Custom Fields** and **Twig**.

I get the images, the titles, and I show them inside the div, all good. Now I want to make the following examble, when the mouse goes on the image, the image will be gradually losing it's down part and the title along with the post order will be shown. I tried mouseover, hover and other stuff but I couldn't make it work. So check it out first, this is a model made by a friend:

[What I wanna do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VvYO.jpg)

This is want I want to do, my project it's like that, with the differences that the titles are underneath the images and the order (01, 02, 03) is not shown. Check the current state here :

[What I have done so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSUTC.jpg)

This is the code used to get the posts from wordpress

```
/* Main file code : */

{% for post in homeserviceposts %} 
    {% include 'category.twig' %}
{% endfor %}

/* Imported file code: */

{% block content %}
<a title="{{post.title}}" href="{{post.link}}">
    {% if post.thumbnail.src %}<img class="img-responsive post-image" src="{{post.thumbnail.src}}"/> {% endif %}
    <h2 class="post-title">{{post.title}}</h2>
</a> {% endblock %}
```

That's basically it, I thank everyone who will spend their time trying to teach me something new!

Comment: Using CSS or JS? Could you please post your full code?

Comment: I am using CSS for this project, the code reguarding my query is the following at CSS, HTML already has being given, Nothing more there.



`.flex-container-posts {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end; 
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 845px;
}

.flex-container-posts a {
  width: 380px;
  text-align: center;
}

.field-article1 {
  height: 900px;
}

.img-responsive {
  width: 405px;
  height: 536px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top: 152px;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your content in another div like this:

```html
<a href="/">
  <div>
    <img src="...">
    <h2>...</h2>
  </div>
</a>
```

and then in the css you set a fixed height plus overflow for the a tag

```css
a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
}
```

and the magic comes when you hover: just translate the image up!

```
a:active > div,
a:focus > div,
a:hover > div {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

and finally add some animation by setting a starting point and a transition to the div

```css
a > div {
  transition: transform 100ms;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

(adjust values to your needs of course)

in wordpress (not 100% familiar with it) it would become something like

```php
{% block content %}
  <a title="{{post.title}}" href="{{post.link}}">
    <div>
      {% if post.thumbnail.src %}
        <img class="img-responsive post-image" src="{{post.thumbnail.src}}"/> 
      {% endif %}
      <h2 class="post-title">{{post.title}}</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you, I get what you're saying, and I didn't know the translate function existed! Can you show me an example based of the code I gave in the query on HTML? I got the CSS all good but I think the way I manage the HTML part is wrong because I end up having 3 a tags and 3 div tags saparate on the page, and the hover is not working, probably because the HTML is out of place. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: I tried :) but my PHP is far away, your end goal should be to have a markup similar to mine (+ any classes you need of course).  You would also need some edge case for the posts where you don't have an image.  If you use `h2:only-child` in CSS you could style those to be centered in the div or something like that, but that would a different question :)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to solve it soon, PHP is quite tricky indeed. Also I hope the client will always put an image on, but yeah I'll to work on the case they won't. Take care! :)